# Meaning of "shall cause" in an association bylaws

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

A HOA Bylaw states that

> The Treasurers shall cause an annual review of HOA books to be made at completion of each fiscal year.

It doesn't say by **whom** the review should be made, or does it assume the Treasurer himself is responsible for reviewing the books?

Is there other than “shall use reasonable efforts to cause", perhaps legal, definition of "shall cause"? If not, the first sentence is ambiguous. By owners? Be professionals?

Either way I don't understand the meaning of the **shall cost** in the above context, or it is incomplete, as "by whom" is omitted.

The sources I used in trying to understand the meaning of "shall cause" are:
https://afterpattern.com/clauses/compliance-with-laws
https://www.adamsdrafting.com/exploring-shall-cause/
https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/shall-cause

Comment: Hello, Valeria. Questions about stipulative legal definitions do not sit well on ELU, where wrong answers have been known to be posted. It is necessary to check with those in authority, those administering the association ... hopefully, they will be abreast of actual legal requirements, including complex interpretations.

Comment: the question is English language related. The definition of "shall cause" and perhaps a sentence structure Subject+Verb+object.

Comment: Yes, but English _legal_ language is a specialised field involving meanings which differ from ordinary usage.

Comment: In everyday English, 'X shall cause Y to be done' where X is some set of sentient agents and Y some result means 'X shall ensure that Y is done'. Whether in legalese (and is all legal language standard throughout the world –  even the Anglophone areas?) there are covert sub-conditions (required methodology, standards say) goes beyond standard English usage. [This ELUMeta thread](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/where-do-we-stand-on-legalese-questions) discusses the problems involved in dealing with legalese.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't say who should do it, it only says it shall be done. If you want to know who should do it, who is legally able to do it, who is competent to do it, that's far off topic here.

Comment: @StuartF this is exactly what I wanted to know

Comment: Of course it won't be the treasurer: they wrote the account books in the first place. It would be an external auditor.

Answer (score 4):

As a recovering lawyer, I will suggest that this language authorizes the Treasurers to engage someone to do this work, rather than obliging them to perform it themselves.

Comment: Could also be simplified to *must arrange* the review. Authorized *and* obligated.